# Algorithm for subset-sum with subtraction

Tags: python, algorithm, subset-sum

I have a subset-sum problem where you can add or subtract the terms. For instance, if I have five terms (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), I want to know how many ways I can add/subtract the terms to make 7:

- 3 + 4
- 2 + 5
- 1 + 2 + 4
- 5 - 2 + 4
- etc.

I wrote some code in Python, but it is very slow once there are many terms:

```
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict

sum_answer = 1
terms = {"T1": 1, "T2": -2, "T3": 3, "T4": -4, "T5": 5}
numlist = [v for v in terms.values()]
zerlist = [x for x in itertools.repeat(0, len(numlist))]
opslist = [item for item in itertools.product((1, -1), repeat=len(numlist))]


res_list = []
for i in range(1, len(numlist)):
    combos = itertools.combinations(numlist, i)

    for x in combos:
        prnlist = list(x) + zerlist[:len(numlist) - len(x)]

        for o in opslist:
            operators = list(o)
            result = []
            res_sum = 0

            for t in range(len(prnlist)):
                if operators[t] == 1:
                    ops = "+"
                else:
                    ops = "-"
                if prnlist[t] != 0:
                    result += [ops, list(terms.keys())[list(terms.values()).index(prnlist[t])]]
                res_sum += operators[t] * prnlist[t]

            if sum_answer == res_sum:
                res_list += [" ".join(result)]

for ans in OrderedDict.fromkeys(res_list).keys():
    print(ans)
```

I realize a million nested loops is terribly inefficient, so are there any parts I can speed up with a better algorithm?

Comment: Since you have a working solution, you'll do best to post this to CodeReview instead of this site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you actually want a list of all solutions, or just a count?

Comment: @PatrickBeeson I disagree, he has a working solution but it is slow. This is an objective problem to be solved.

Comment: @HughBothwell: The purpose is to try and find which fields in a database are used in the calculation of a total on a report, so I need all solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea is mostly right: generate each combination of the terms, do the sum and see if it's a hit. You can optimize your code though.

The problem is that once you generate `1 + 2`, you see that it's not a match for your desired sum and throw it away. However, if you add `4` to it, it's a solution. You won't get to that solution until you generate `1 + 2 + 4` though, when you will compute the sum from scratch. You also generate the possibilities of adding the operators from scratch for each combination, which also does a lot of redundant work for the same reason.

You also use a lot of lists operations, which can be slow.

I would do this:

```
def solve(terms_list, stack, current_s, desired_s):
    if len(terms_list) == 0:
        if current_s == desired_s:
            print(stack)
        return

    for w in [0, 1, -1]: # ignore term (0), add it (1), subtract it (-1)
        stack.append(w)
        solve(terms_list[1:], stack, current_s + w * terms_list[0], desired_s)
        stack.pop()
```

The initial call is, for example, `solve([1,2,3,4,5], [], 0, 7)`.

Note that this has complexity `O(3^n)` (kinda, read on), because each term can be added, subtracted or ignored.

The complexity of my actual implementation is `O(n*3^n)`, because the recursive call makes a copy of the `terms_list` parameter. You can avoid this however, but I wanted to make the code simpler and also leave that as an exercise. You can also avoid constructing the actual expression before printing it and construct it incrementally instead, but you might need more parameters for that.

However, `O(3^n)` is still a lot, and you shouldn't expect it to do very well for large `n` no matter what you do.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to "regular" subset sum problem - where you use [DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to solve the problem, you will also use it here, but will need to have one more possibility - reduce the current element instead of adding it.

```
f(0,i) = 1               //successive subset
f(x,0) = 0    x>0        //failure subset
f(x,i) = f(x+element[i],i-1) + f(x-element[i],i-1) + f(x,i-1)
                                 ^^^
               This is the added option for substraction
```

When translating it to bottom-up DP solution, you will need to create a matrix of size `(SUM+1) * (2n+1)`, where `SUM` is the sum of all elements and `n` is the number of elements.

Comment: The OP's implementation seems to print the actual solutions, not just count them.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are trying to brute-force all possible combinations of field-values from one row (then validity-test each combination against the other rows).

I presume you have lots of rows of data to play with; I suggest you take advantage of that by taking a bunch of rows (at least as many as you have fields to solve for) and applying an approximate matrix solver like [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).

This has a number of important advantages:

- allows you to sanely handle rounding-error problems (necessary if any of your fields are non-integer)
- allows you to easily handle fields whose coefficient is not in `{-1, 0, 1}`, ie tax rates whose coefficient may be something like `0.12`
- uses fully-supported code that you don't have to debug or maintain
- uses highly optimized code that will run considerably faster *(** most likely, depending on what options your numpy was compiled with)*
- has insanely better time complexity (something like O(n ** 2.8) instead of O(3 ** n)) which means it should scale to considerably more fields

So, some test data:

```
import numpy as np

# generate test data
def make_test_data(coeffs, mean=20.0, base=0.05):
    w      = len(coeffs)    # number of fields
    h      = int(1.5 * w)   # number of rows of data
    rows   = np.random.exponential(mean - base, (h, w)) + base
    totals = data.dot(coeffs)
    return rows.round(2), totals.round(2)
```

which gives us something like

```
>>> rows, totals = make_test_data([0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0.12])

>>> print(rows)
[[  1.45  17.63  22.54   5.54  37.06   1.47]
 [ 11.71  80.43  26.43  18.48  11.08   8.8 ]
 [ 16.09  11.34  63.74   3.31  13.2   13.35]
 [ 11.96  12.17  10.23   8.15  73.3    0.42]
 [  4.03   8.01  20.84  21.46   2.76  18.98]
 [  3.24   6.6   35.06  23.17   9.03   8.58]
 [ 25.05  33.72   6.82   0.49  46.76  12.21]
 [ 70.27   1.48  23.05   0.69  31.11  43.13]
 [  9.04  10.45  15.08   4.32  52.94  11.13]]

>>> print(totals)
[  3.29  96.84  63.48 -50.85  28.37  33.66  -4.75  -1.4  -26.07]
```

and the solver code,

```
>>> sol = np.linalg.lstsq(rows, totals)    # one line!

>>> print(sol[0])       # note the solutions are not *exact*
[ -1.485730e-04  1.000072e+00  9.999334e-01 -7.992023e-05 -9.999552e-01  1.203379e-01]

>>> print(sol[0].round(3))      # but they are *very* close
[ 0.    1.    1.    0.   -1.    0.12]
```